# Cycling LED's for specific time period with millis()

Tags: millis

My goal in pseudo code is :

```
only LED-6 HIGH for 6 seconds, then only LED-7 HIGH for 2 seconds, then only LED-8 HIGH for 4 seconds, then restart
```

This is very easy with delay(), but I struggle with millis(). Here is my code. Only led 7 and 8 blinks.

```
unsigned long currentTime;
unsigned long previousTime1 = 0;
unsigned long previousTime2 = 0;
unsigned long previousTime3 = 0;
unsigned long interval1 = 6000;
unsigned long interval2 = 2000;
unsigned long interval3 = 4000;

void setup() {

  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);


}

void loop() {

  currentTime = millis();

  if (currentTime - previousTime1 >= interval1){
    previousTime1 = currentTime;
    digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(7, LOW);
    digitalWrite(8, LOW);
  }

  if (currentTime - previousTime2 >= interval2){
    previousTime2 = currentTime;
    digitalWrite(6, LOW);
    digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(8, LOW);
  }

   if (currentTime - previousTime3 >= interval3){
    previousTime3 = currentTime;
    digitalWrite(6, LOW);
    digitalWrite(7, LOW);
    digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to make this work is to use only one `previousTime` variable, rather than three of them.

When the program as shown above starts out, `millis()` is in fact close to 0, so none of the three LEDs should light up in the first 2 seconds.  At the 2 second mark, LED 7 comes on.  `previousTime2` gets set to current time, so the second `if` is not going to be satisfied for 2 more seconds.  At that point, LED 7 and 8 are in a race to see which one turns on second; whichever turns on first at the 4-second mark gets turned off within milliseconds, because when any LED turns on, the code turns off the other two LEDs.  Whenever the condition for LED 6 is met, so is the condition for at least one of 7 or 8; so 6 can't stay on more than 2 seconds at most, and even then is in a race with 7 and 8 to come in third.

With a single `previousTime` variable, code like the following might work.

```
current = (millis() - previousTime)/1000;
if (current < 6) {
  digitalWrite(6, HIGH); // turn on 6
} else {
  digitalWrite(6, LOW);  // turn off 6
}
if (current >= 6 && current < 8) {
  digitalWrite(7, HIGH); // turn on 7
} else {
  digitalWrite(7, LOW);  // turn off 7
}
if (current >= 8) {
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH); // turn on 8
} else {
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);  // turn off 8
}
if (current >= 12) {
  previousTime = millis();
}
```

Note, the following code has the same effect.

```
current = (millis() - previousTime)/1000;
digitalWrite(6, current < 6);                 // turn 6 on or off
digitalWrite(7, current >= 6 && current < 8); // turn 7 on or off
digitalWrite(8, current >= 8);                // turn 8 on or off
if (current >= 12) {
  previousTime = millis();
}
```